# primefaces layoutUnit f:facet header

Tags: primefaces

how to set layoutUnit header with f:facet. the following code is not working!
thanks

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true"> 
            <f:facet name="header">my header</f:facet>

 </p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: why do you want to set it using f:facet? Just set the attribute header="my header".

Comment: layoutUnit is used in a template, and the header value depends on the client

Comment: Maybe you can try <f:attribute name="header" value="myHeader">

Answer (score 2):

use

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<pe:layout>
   <pe:layoutPane id="navigator-pane" >
    <f:facet name="header">
    </f:facet>
   </pe:layoutPane>
</pe:layout>
```

from primefaces-extensions library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In primefaces the header of the layoutUnit is defined by the property header like that:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" header="HEADER" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
</p:layoutUnit>
```

So, if you were using primeface-extensions then yes could change the header that way submitted by you.